# disabling close button in QMessagBox in PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I am using python and PyQt5 for making a pop-up in a GUI. And I want to disable the close button in my pop-up. The code that I am using now looks like this. Given below is a pseudo code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

option_box = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
option_box.setWindowFlags(option_box.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
```

the problem is that setWindowFalgs option does not seem to work for me.

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which close button are you talking about ? The one on the top corner or an actual button on the pop up ?

Comment: The one on the top right corner. The one that we get by default

Comment: According to documentation you need to set the flag CustomizeWindowHint to be able to customize this part of the window.

Comment: @Viper can you also post link to documentation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the doc : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum

Comment: I can't find an anchor to the specific part, but it says : "The CustomizeWindowHint flag is used to enable customization of the window controls. This flag must be set to allow the WindowTitleHint, WindowSystemMenuHint, WindowMinimizeButtonHint, WindowMaximizeButtonHint and WindowCloseButtonHint flags to be changed."

Comment: @Viper if it is not too much trouble, can you paste pseudo code? I am not able to figure out how to do.

Comment: Well I wasn't able to quickly figure it either, but thankfully @Austin did it

Answer (score 1):

The **CustomizeWindowHint** flag has to be set to enable the Hint flags to be changed, plus you need to disable the **WindowSystemMenuHint** flag too.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

option_box = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
option_box.setWindowFlags(option_box.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
option_box.setWindowFlags(option_box.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
option_box.setWindowFlags(option_box.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint)
```

Comment: This works in removing the close button. But there is one problem now. I added a custom icon in the message box which is not visible. 
The code that I used was.

```
option_box.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
        os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'images', 'icon.png')))
```

Comment: @programmer_04_03 That's because they removed the system menu hint, which is what shows the icon. Just remove the last line.

Comment: @programmer-04-03 I encountered the same problem, but haven't found the solution. It needs both hint flags deselecting to hide the close button, but that also removes the icon.